# Python Conceptual Query

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python. I'm stuck upon a problem. Kindly clear my doubt.

```
a='abc'
b='abc'
a==b                 #When I run this O/P is True. But, in C/C++ or Java it turns out to be False because the variables(a & b) refer to different memories.

a is b               #When I run this O/P is True. Ok understood , but.....
```

BUT WHEN

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
a==b                #The out put is True

a is b              #THe output is False
```

What is the reason for the two different outputs in the case of strings and lists?

Comment: Small strings and integers are *interned*; cached and only one object is created for the lifetime of the interpreter. `is` tests identity (same object), so `a` and `b` are the *same object*. The lists are two separate objects that happen to represent the same value (equal).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: Actually, a direct translation of your first snippet to C (`const char *a = "abc"; ... a == b`) or Java (`String a = "abc"; ... a == b`) yields true, because string literals are interned there too.

Comment: @delnan- Thanks for pointing that out. But I was talking wen I compare 2 chars...for eg= char a[4]='abc' and char b[4]='abc' and then comparing them yields False.

Comment: My question actually is Why a is b in case of list is False but in case of strings it's True. Why

Comment: @MartijnPieters-- +1 for your answer.<br> I tried it for A=1 and B=1. then A is B yields True. and for A=257 , B=257 yields False. Thanks